# Convert array-of-hashes to a hash-of-hashes, indexed by an attribute of the hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, hash

I've got an array of hashes representing objects as a response to an API call. I need to pull data from some of the hashes, and one particular key serves as an id for the hash object. I would like to convert the array into a hash with the keys as the ids, and the values as the original hash with that id.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
api_response = [
  { :id => 1, :foo => 'bar' },
  { :id => 2, :foo => 'another bar' },
  # ..
]

ideal_response = {
  1 => { :id => 1, :foo => 'bar' },
  2 => { :id => 2, :foo => 'another bar' },
  # ..
}
```

There are two ways I could think of doing this.

1. Map the data to the `ideal_response` (below)
2. Use `api_response.find { |x| x[:id] == i }` for each record I need to access.
3. A method I'm unaware of, possibly involving a way of using `map` to build a hash, natively.

My method of mapping:

```
keys = data.map { |x| x[:id] }
mapped = Hash[*keys.zip(data).flatten]
```

I can't help but feel like there is a more performant, tidier way of doing this. Option 2 is very performant when there are a very minimal number of records that need to be accessed. Mapping excels here, but it starts to break down when there are a lot of records in the response. Thankfully, I don't expect there to be more than 50-100 records, so mapping is sufficient.

**Is there a smarter, tidier, or more performant way of doing this in Ruby?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Ruby <= 2.0**

```
> Hash[api_response.map { |r| [r[:id], r] }]
#=> {1=>{:id=>1, :foo=>"bar"}, 2=>{:id=>2, :foo=>"another bar"}}
```

However, [Hash::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) is pretty ugly and breaks the usual left-to-right OOP flow. That's why [Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/) proposed [Enumerable#mash](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-mash):

```
> require 'facets'
> api_response.mash { |r| [r[:id], r] }
#=> {1=>{:id=>1, :foo=>"bar"}, 2=>{:id=>2, :foo=>"another bar"}}
```

This basic abstraction (convert enumerables to hashes) was asked to be included in Ruby long ago, alas, [without luck](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/666).

Note that your use case is covered by Active Support: [Enumerable#index_by](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/index_by)

**Ruby >= 2.1**

**[UPDATE]** Still no love for `Enumerable#mash`, but now we have [Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h). It creates an intermediate array, but it's better than nothing:

```
> object = api_response.map { |r| [r[:id], r] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
ideal_response = api_response.group_by{|i| i[:id]} 
#=> {1=>[{:id=>1, :foo=>"bar"}], 2=>[{:id=>2, :foo=>"another bar"}]}
```

It uses Enumerable's `group_by`, which works on collections, returning matches for whatever key value you want. Because it expects to find multiple occurrences of matching key-value hits it appends them to arrays, so you end up with a hash of arrays of hashes. You could peel back the internal arrays if you wanted but could run a risk of overwriting content if two of your hash IDs collided. `group_by` avoids that with the inner array.

Accessing a particular element is easy:

```
ideal_response[1][0]       #=> {:id=>1, :foo=>"bar"}
ideal_response[1][0][:foo] #=> "bar"
```

The way you show at the end of the question is another valid way of doing it. Both are reasonably fast and elegant.

Comment: This is better than the mapping I had in terms of performance and tidiness, but accessing records via `data[id][0]` or `data[id].first` is a bit cumbersome. I'm nitpicking at this point, though. Let's see if anybody else cares to throw their hat in the ring.

Comment: That's the result of a possibility of running into a duplicate key. `group_by` is a generic routine designed for safety with unknown data. Having applications-specific knowledge, such as knowing you'll never, ever, encounter a duplicate and the ensuing key collision and data loss, would allow simplifying the data structure by one level.

Answer (score 0):

For this I'd probably just go:

```
ideal_response = api_response.each_with_object(Hash.new) { |o, h| h[o[:id]] = o }
```

Not super pretty with the multiple brackets in the block but it does the trick with just a single iteration of the api_response.

Answer (score 0):

```
ideal_response = {}
api_response.each do |response|
  ideal_response[response[:id]] = response
end
```

O(n) where n is the length of api_response